# Adding attachments in list instance

Tags: list, attachments, elements-xml

As we can add list instances in **element.xml**, is there a way to attach an image in **Attachments** field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a no.

> I don't believe this is possible using Data for the ListInstance.  I
>   tried saving a list as a template including data which had a list item
>   with an attachment.  Then downloaded the STP, renamed to a CAB and
>   extracted the manifest.xml.  There wasn't any attributes which stood
>   out and the STP also contained a file called 10000000.000 which I
>   believe was my attachment.  SharePoint is doing something behind the
>   scenes, because of this I think the only approach would be to create
>   the list item programatically using a Feature Receiver and attaching
>   the file.  An example of setting the attachment can be found here
>   http://avinashkt.blogspot.com/2009/05/how-to-programmatically-attach-document.html

[List Instance with data](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/0279995b-1f91-4e5e-bd7c-72deea81d197/list-instance-with-data)